# How to call $setValidity in directive only if required attribute exists

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive where I call this:

```
ngModel.$setValidity('required', isFinite(scope.inputValue) && scope.inputValue != null);
```

to set whether the value has been filled by the user or not. I'm pretty sure this used to only make the form invalid if my directive had `required` or `ng-required="trueExpression"` on it, but since upgrading to Angular v1.5.7 the form appears to become invalid regardless of whether the required attributes exist or not.

So how can I detect if `required` or `ng-required="trueExpression"` are on my directive so I only call this line then?

Here is my entire directive for reference:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').directive('bigNumberInput', bigNumberInput);

    bigNumberInput.$inject = [];

    function bigNumberInput() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            require: 'ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                label: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/directives/bigNumberInput.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                //scope.inputValue = null;

                ngModel.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                    var inputValue = null;
                    var sizeValue = "";

                    if (modelValue != null) {
                        if (modelValue / 1000000000 >= 1.0) {
                            inputValue = modelValue / 1000000000;
                            sizeValue = "B";
                        } else if (modelValue / 1000000 >= 1.0) {
                            inputValue = modelValue / 1000000;
                            sizeValue = "MM";
                        } else if (modelValue / 1000 >= 1.0) {
                            inputValue = modelValue / 1000;
                            sizeValue = "K";
                        } else {
                            inputValue = modelValue;
                            sizeValue = "";
                        }
                    }

                    return { inputValue: inputValue, sizeValue: sizeValue };
                });

                ngModel.$render = function () {
                    scope.inputValue = ngModel.$viewValue.inputValue;
                    scope.sizeValue = ngModel.$viewValue.sizeValue;
                };

                scope.$watch('inputValue + sizeValue', function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue({
                        inputValue: scope.inputValue,
                        sizeValue: scope.sizeValue
                    });

                    ngModel.$setValidity('required', isFinite(scope.inputValue) && scope.inputValue != null);
                });

                ngModel.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                    var inputValue = viewValue.inputValue;
                    if (inputValue != null) {
                        if (viewValue.sizeValue === 'K') {
                            inputValue = inputValue * 1000;
                        } else if (viewValue.sizeValue === "MM") {
                            inputValue = inputValue * 1000000;
                        } else if (viewValue.sizeValue === "B") {
                            inputValue = inputValue * 1000000000;
                        }
                    }
                    return inputValue;
                });
            }
        };
    }
}());
```

And here is the HTML template for it:

```
<div layout="row">
    <md-input-container flex>
        <label>{{label}}</label>
        <input type="number" step="any" ng-model="inputValue"/>
        <div ng-transclude></div>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
        <label>Type</label>
        <md-select ng-model="sizeValue" md-on-open="valuationTypeOpen = true" md-on-close="valuationTypeOpen = false">
            <md-option value="">{{valuationTypeOpen ? 'Verbatim (=)' : '='}}</md-option>
            <md-option value="K">{{valuationTypeOpen ? 'Thousands (K)' : 'K'}}</md-option>
            <md-option value="MM">{{valuationTypeOpen ? 'Millions (MM)' : 'MM'}}</md-option>
            <md-option value="B">{{valuationTypeOpen ? 'Billions (B)' : 'B'}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Comment: on input field add that directive as below - <input type="text" name="test" ng-model="ngModel">

Comment: @NagaSaiA, I included my whole directive. Can you advise on how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer on my own. I believe it's just a matter checking if the "required" attribute returns true like this:

```
ngModel.$setValidity('required', !attrs.required || (isFinite(scope.inputValue) && scope.inputValue != null));
```

It appears to be working for hard-coded `required` attributes as well as using `ng-required` attributes.